# Change user profile image on profile page to activate colorbox

Tags: 7, users, javascript

This is for Drupal 7.

Currently on the default user profile page, the profile picture just links back to their profile.  I'd like to change this so it opens a colorbox.  Thoughts?

**SOLUTION**

Add the following to your theme's template.php file.

```
<?php
function ccom_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {
  $variables['user_picture'] = '';
  $original_image = NULL; 
  if (variable_get('user_pictures', 0)) {
    $account = $variables['account'];
    if (!empty($account->picture)) {
      // @TODO: Ideally this function would only be passed file objects, but
      // since there's a lot of legacy code that JOINs the {users} table to
      // {node} or {comments} and passes the results into this function if we
      // a numeric value in the picture field we'll assume it's a file id
      // and load it for them. Once we've got user_load_multiple() and
      // comment_load_multiple() functions the user module will be able to load
      // the picture files in mass during the object's load process.
      if (is_numeric($account->picture)) {
        $account->picture = file_load($account->picture);
      }
      if (!empty($account->picture->uri)) {
        $filepath = $account->picture->uri;
      }
    }
    elseif (variable_get('user_picture_default', '')) {
      $filepath = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    }
    if (isset($filepath)) {
      $alt = t("@user's picture", array('@user' => format_username($account)));
      // If the image does not have a valid Drupal scheme (for eg. HTTP),
      // don't load image styles.
      if (module_exists('image') && file_valid_uri($filepath) && $style = variable_get('user_picture_style', '')) {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => $style, 'path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));
        $original_image = image_style_url('large', $filepath);
      }
      else {
        $variables['user_picture'] = theme('image', array('path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt));
      }
      if (!empty($account->uid) && user_access('access user profiles')) {
        if (isset($original_image)) {
          $attributes = array(
            'attributes' => array('title' => t('View expanded image.'), 'class' => t('colorbox')),
            'html' => TRUE,
          );
          $variables['user_picture'] = l($variables['user_picture'], "$original_image", $attributes);
        }
        else {
          $attributes = array(
            'attributes' => array('title' => t('View user profile.')),
            'html' => TRUE,
          );
          $variables['user_picture'] = l($variables['user_picture'], "user/$account->uid", $attributes);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Theme API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/template_preprocess_user_picture/7) is your friend.