# How to make user picture editable without opening edit profile page?

Tags: 7, users, entities, media, panels

I wanted to allow users to edit profile without going to edit profile page. I found few useful modules like [Editable field](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) and [Editable fields as link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields_as_link). These modules provide field formatter which make the field editable without leaving the page except the user picture. I am not able to use this technique with user pictures because It is not a normal field as other fields.

How can I make user picture an editable field without going to edit profile page?

**Note: I have created a custom profile page using panels. There is a module [Picture Changer](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile_pic_changer) which allows users to change picture in a modal, but it does not work with panels.**

Comment: I guess if there is something which makes/converts the user picture field act as other normal field, will do the trick. But the question is, what? I have found this [post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23564/change-user-profile-image-on-profile-page-to-activate-colorbox), but not sure how it can be helpful.

Comment: anybody home?...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own form where a user can upload the picture and save it as profile picture.

Comment: How would such form look like?

Comment: Hi Bram, your answer is really short. Could you provide an example of such a form?